# Why use mixin of padding and margin in sass?

Tags: html, css, sass

I know why to use sass but I want to know why use mixin of padding and margin?
Kindly look into this example:

```
@mixin padding($top, $right, $bottom, $left) {
  padding-top: $top;
  padding-right: $right;
  padding-bottom: $bottom;
  padding-left: $left;
}
//Margin mixin
@mixin margin($top, $right, $bottom, $left) {
  margin-top: $top;
  margin-right: $right;
  margin-bottom: $bottom;
  margin-left: $left;
}
//usage defination:

@include padding(top, right, bottom, left); // one line code
@include margin(top, right, bottom, left);  // one line code
```

css code:

```
 padding: 1px 2px 3px 4px; // one line code
 margin: 1px 2px 3px 4px;  // one line code
```

so why to use margin padding mixin of sass as all are taking one line of code only??

Comment: It's not at all required. Some newbie might have written that code or might be using it. You can completely ignore as it does not make any sense.

Comment: If it's just an *example* then it does not have to be useful (just a minimal example of how the thing looks like... In a language documentation for instance, it's pretty impossible to give an example of a usable mixin w/o introducing a few more complex concepts first).

Answer (score 4):

@mixin, repetitive and conditional sentences @each, @if in Sass are very useful if you need to generate some useful style classes in this case for margin and padding, here I made a util Sass code for margin and padding classes following this [Spacing helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/spacing) that are useful for modifying the padding and margin of an element.

```
//padding, margin spacer vars 
$spacer: 16;
$max: 5;
$zero: 0px;
$one: unquote( ( $spacer * 0.25  ) + 'px' );
$two: unquote( ( $spacer * 0.5  ) + 'px' );
$three: unquote( ( $spacer ) + 'px' );
$four: unquote( ( $spacer * 1.5 ) + 'px' );
$five: unquote( ( $spacer * 3 ) + 'px' );

$spaces: ($zero, $one, $two, $three, $four, $five); // Adjust this to include the pixel amounts you need.
$sides: (x, y, all, top, bottom, left, right); // Leave this variable alone
$i: 0;
@each $space in $spaces {
    @each $side in $sides {
        @if $side == all {
            .pa-#{$i} {
                padding: #{$space} #{$space} !important;
            }
        } @else if $side == x {
            .px-#{$i} {
                padding-left: #{$space} !important;
                padding-right: #{$space} !important;
            }
        } @else if $side == y {
            .py-#{$i} {
                padding-top: #{$space} !important;
                padding-bottom: #{$space} !important;
            }
        } @else {
            .p#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{$i} {
                padding-#{$side}: #{$space} !important;
            }
        }
    }
    @each $side in $sides {
        @if $side == all {
            .ma-#{$i} {
                margin: #{$space} #{$space} !important;
            }
        } @else if $side == x {
            .mx-#{$i} {
                margin-left: #{$space} !important;
                margin-right: #{$space} !important;
            }
        } @else if $side == y {
            .my-#{$i} {
                margin-top: #{$space} !important;
                margin-bottom: #{$space} !important;
            }
        } @else {
            .m#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{$i} {
                margin-#{$side}: #{$space} !important;
            }
        }
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
}
```

**How it works:**
The helper classes apply margin or padding to an element ranging from 0 to 5. Each size increment was designed to align with common Material Design spacings. These classes can be applied using the following format **{property}{direction}-{size}**.

The property applies the type of spacing:

**m** - applies margin
**p** - applies padding
The direction designates the side the property applies to:

- **t** - applies the spacing for ***-top**
- **b** - applies the spacing for ***-bottom**
- **l** - applies the spacing for ***-left**
- **r** - applies the spacing for ***-right**
- **x** - applies the spacing for both ***-left*** and **-right**
- **y** - applies the spacing for both ***-top*** and **-bottom**
- **a** - applies the spacing for the property in all directions

For example **padding-top: 4px;** will create a CSS class:

```
.pt-1 {
  padding-top: 4px !important;
}
```

You can find more detailed documentation [Vuetify spacing doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/spacing).
I made this code taking the idea from [jacurtis/_spacing-helpers.scss](https://gist.github.com/jacurtis/30da4bf9a6c9b9b5cc0aebac512ca7c9) and making some modification to fit my needs.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mixin is probably only helpful when you are repeating several different properties such as padding AND margin.  Then you could use something like this and only use one line of CSS:

```
@mixin margin-padding($m-direction, $m-amount, $p-direction, $p-amount) {
  @if $m-direction == all {
    margin: $m-amount;
  } @else {
    margin-#{$m-direction}: $m-amount;
  }
  @if $p-direction == all {
    padding: $p-amount;
  } @else {
    padding-#{$p-direction}: $p-amount;
  }
}
```

You could even use null values if you aren't using one of the properties.

CSS code examples:

```
.some-class {
  @include margin-padding(all, 5% 0, bottom, 5%);
}

.some-other-class {
  @include margin-padding(all, 0 auto 5%, null, null);
}
```

Which would compile to:

```
.some-class {
  margin: 5% 0;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.some-other-class {
  margin: 0 auto 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use padding and margin mixin to limit variations of padding and margin values that can be applied on each element. I call it a micro-grid system.

This way, your frontend developers and UX don't go come up with all kind of padding and margin values. Instead, padding and margin values remain consistent.

```
//map that defines key value pair of well-defined spacing range
$spaces: (none: 0,
3xs: 3px,
2xs: 5px,
1xs: 10px,
sm: 15px,
md: 20px,
lg: 25px,
1xl: 30px,
2xl: 35px,
4xl: 40px);

//padding mixin that takes direction of padding that needs to be applied
//and one spacing qualifier (in this case, anywhere between 3xs to 3xl).
//you will also do the same for margin mixin
@mixin padding($direction: all, $size: md) {
   @if $direction == all {
       @include spacer(padding, $size);
   }
   @else @if $direction == left {
       @include spacer(padding-left, $size);
   }
   @else @if $direction == right {
       @include spacer(padding-right, $size);
   }
   @else @if $direction == top {
       @include spacer(padding-top, $size);
   }
   @else @if $direction == bottom {
       @include spacer(padding-bottom, $size);
   }
   @else @if $direction == x {
       @include spacer(padding-left, $size);
       @include spacer(padding-right, $size);
   }
   @else @if $direction == y {
       @include spacer(padding-top, $size);
       @include spacer(padding-bottom, $size);
   }
}

//just another helper mixin to avoid repeating code
@mixin spacer($attribute, $unit) {
   #{$attribute}: map-get($spacing, $unit);
}

//mixin in action
.hero-area {
   @include padding(y, 3xl);
}
```